# How do I use gtsv2 functions of the cusparse library in CUDA Fortran?

Tags: cuda, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have been using `cusparseDgtsv` for solving tridiagonal matrices with multiple right-hand sides. I recently found `cusparseDgtsv2` which improves concurrency. However the documentation says that `cusparseDgtsv2` expects a `void *pBuffer argument`, and `cusparseDgtsv2_bufferSizeExt` expects a `size_t *bufferSizeInBytes` argument. What kind of argument should I use for the `void` and `size_t` counterpart in CUDA Fortran?

***EDIT**

```
cusparseStatus_t cusparseDgtsv2(
    cusparseHandle_t handle,
    int m,        
    int n,        
    const double *dl,  
    const double  *d,    
    const double *du, 
    double *B,     
    int ldb,
    void *pBuffer)
```

@SteveLionel I wrote the following code which works fine, but when calling the function `cusparseDgtsv2`, I get a warning message saying "Argument to ISO_C_BINDING intrinsic must have TARGET attribute set." Also, is there a better way of allocating `N` bytes in Fortran rather than using `character` arrays?

```
function cusparseDgtsv2 (h,m,n,dl,d,du,B,ldb,pBuffer) bind(C,name='cusparseDgtsv2')
   use iso_c_binding
   use cusparse
   type (cusparseHandle), value :: h
   integer (c_int), value  :: m,n
   real (c_double), device :: dl(*)
   real (c_double), device :: d(*)
   real (c_double), device :: du(*)
   real (c_double), device :: B(*)
   integer (c_int), value  :: ldb
   type (c_ptr),    value  :: pBuffer
   integer (c_int), value  :: cusparseDgtsv2
end function

integer :: istat
integer :: m, n
integer (c_size_t) :: N
type (cusparseHandle) :: handle
real, allocatable, device :: d_A(:), d_B(:), d_C(:), d_D(:)
character, allocatable, device :: buf(:)

allocate (buf(N))
istat = cusparseDgtsv2 ( handle, m, n, d_A, d_B, d_C, d_D, m, c_loc(buf) )
```

Comment: You can learn about Fortran C interoperability with questions under [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].

Comment: You are not showing the intrinsic that causes the warning about `target`. It is a new issue. Your original issue is solved. Avoid asking too many questions per post, especially after you got answers.

Comment: @VladimirF The warning message occurs when calling `cusparseDgtsv2` of the last line. I suppose it has to do with c_loc(buf). By the way, I added the second question because I thought it was related to using gtsv2 functions in general. I will post a new question for this. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I can see it now. It was because you did not use charecter(kind=c_char).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Fortran 2018, C `void` didn't have a Fortran equivalent. Compilers that support the "Further Interoperability with C" features of F2018 support `type(*)` that is interoperable with `void *`. I don't know which compiler you're using - if it's PGI, I don't think they support this yet.

An alternative is to declare the argument as `type(C_PTR)` along with the `value` attribute. You would then pass `C_LOC(arg)`.

For `size_t`, that's `integer(C_SIZE_T)`. All of these assume you have added `USE ISO_C_BINDING`, that your interface for the procedure has `BIND(C)`, and that your compiler supports at least the F2003 C interoperability features.